# Piping without transmitting EOT

Tags: piping

I'm looking for a way to pipe without sending an EOT (Ctrl-D), i.e. making these equivalent:

```
bob@bob-pc:~$ cat
porkchop
porkchop
```

and

```
bob@bob-pc:~$ echo -n pork | cat
porkbob@bob-pc:~$ chop
No command 'chop' found
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, to some extent:

```
bob@bob-pc:~$ ( echo -n pork ; while read l; do echo $l; done ) |cat
porkchop
chop
```

But a less tedious solution would still be nice.